# Why does Jekyll/Liquid split filter ignore trailing delimiters?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

The jekyll/liquid `split` string filter is briefly documented [here](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#split). When applying `split` to URL's I realized that `split` has a quite surprising behavior when the string being split has as first or last character the split delimiter. See examples on [this test page](https://wfjm.github.io/tests/jekyll_split.html).

```
--> split of '/a/b/c' by '/' gives ["","a","b","c"]
--> split of 'a/b/c/' by '/' gives ["a","b","c"]
```

A leading delimiter produces an empty leading string list element
A trailing delimiter seems to be ignored.

That's why `split:'/' | join:'/'` does not reproduce the original string
as one might naively expect.

Questions:

1. Is that, to me surprising, asymmetric behavior intended ?
2. If yes, why ?
3. If yes, why isn't it clearly documented ?